# How to remove indicators from owl carousel

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I cannot for the life of me get rid of them:

```
dots: false,
```

Doesn't do anything?

Comment: Which version of OwlCarousel are you using?

Comment: https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.css

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Since you are using OwlCarousel version 1, please check out [their documentation](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/index.html#customizing). This also says pagination (dots) can be turned off with:

```
pagination: false,
```

The `dots: false,` is for version 2. See [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/OwlFonk/OwlCarousel/issues/321) which is asking the same question.

Comment: Cheers. Also, how do I get rid of the grey around my image if I use left and right arrow images for "navigationText"?

Comment: @JSHD No problem. Please mark my answer as correct if this solved your issue, so others can benefit from it as well. I'll check on the grey borders in a sec.

Comment: @JSHD I'm not sure if there's a boolean attribute to delete the grey area around the slider. You could do this with css possibly, but maybe it's better if you make a new Question for that particular issue.

Answer (score 20):

```
<pre>
<code>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
                dots: false,
            });
        });
    </script>

</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: While this code possibly answers the question, providing additional [context](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) regarding _how_ and/or _why_ it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. It also doesn't hurt to mention why this answer is more appropriate than others.

Answer (score 5):

Try as below:

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
  nav: false,
  dots: false,
.....
..
```

Answer (score 4):

For version 2 you can use the dots property.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    // ... other properties
    dots: false,
    // ... other properties
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try as below:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
        require(['jquery','owlcarousel'], function($){
            $(document).ready(function() {
               $('#feature_product').owlCarousel({
                    margin: 10,
                    dots:false,
                    loop: true,
                    autoplay: true,
                    autoplayTimeout:300,
                    slideSpeed : 200,
                    responsiveClass:true,
                    responsive:{
                        0:{
                            items:1,
                            nav:true
                        },
                        600:{
                            items:3,
                            nav:true
                        },
                        1000:{
                            items:5,
                            nav:true,
                            loop:true
                        },
                    }
                });

              });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Hey Rakesh - Can you please add some details/description before your code snippet. That will be very helpful for the asker as well as the community to understand your post fully.

Answer (score 0):

$(".carousel1").owlCarousel({
           margin: 20,
           loop: true,
           autoplay: true,
           autoplayTimeout: 2000,
           autoplayHoverPause: true,
           nav: false,
           dots: false,
           responsive: {
             0:{
               items:1,
               nav: false
             },
             600:{
               items:2,
               nav: false
             },
             1000:{
               items:3,
               nav: false
             }
           }
         });

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).